# How do I find the device which has Com Port X reserved - want to reclaim the port num for different device

Tags: windows, windows-registry, serial-port

I added a 4 port pci serial card to my **windows 7** PC.  I want to assign them COM1-4.

I know how to change the COM Port Number when the com port number is **not already in use.**

In my case, COM4 is taken by something... probably some type of usb to serial device I connected at some point.  If I knew what it was I could connect it and then change the com port through the Device Manager -> Ports -> dialogs.

But, I have no idea what the device has reserved com4.  I'm assuming there is a registry setting or some device descriptor file somewhere that I need to remove.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Method Using Elevated Command Prompt"

From Start Menu
type cmd into search bar
**right click on cmd.exe** and **select run as administrator**

at UAC select **yes** to allow Windows Command Processor Program to make changes.

At the Command prompt type

**SET DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1**    (Followed by enter)

Then to open device manager type

**DEVMGMT.MSC**     (Followed by enter)

In device Manager select **View** / **Show hidden devices**

Expand Ports (COM & LPT)

Hidden ports reserved will be shown with greyed out symbol & associated manufacturer / device type

[image: screen shot device manager ports]

To re-hide non present devices in future - from an elevated Command prompt type

**SET DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=0**    (Followed by enter)

Comment: Looks super promising!  Can't wait to try this.  Thanks Antony.

Comment: You are the man.  I've come back to this post like 4 times already.  I wish I could upvote you more!

Comment: thanks, glad to assist, I remember when I first found out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

(For those who came from google)
If the previous answer doesn't work and has installed Windows mobile 6 SDK. It may be problem with XPVCOM.SYS (this driver reserved 14 COM ports) 
To uninstall in the console:

```
CD \Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Tools\Cellular Emulator\
InstallXPVCom.exe UnInstall
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)