# Determining what program is using the COM ports

Tags: windows-10, usb, com

I am on Win10, trying to upload a sketch to Arduino and it is telling me the COM port (a USB port) is being used. I do have another Qt-based program which normally uses the COM port but I believe I have turned off the program before I tried to upload the sketch. Hence, I wish to see what program is using the COM ports. [Previous answers](https://superuser.com/questions/796258/com-port-in-use) suggested I download external software to resolve this issue but in my case I cannot download external software. Please let me know if more information is required to solve this issue.

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/389539/how-do-i-find-the-device-which-has-com-port-x-reserved-want-to-reclaim-the-por) help?

Comment: You might also try Nirsoft's free utility, USBDeview , https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html